# How to include a Zebra barcode reader on a J2EE website

Tags: jakarta-ee, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to implement a zebra barcode reader on a website (in J2EE technology). The idea is when a person consult the site from a mobile phone he/she will be able to scan a zebra barcode.

All I could find was android solution (like ZXing). Do you know any Java api that would do the job ? Maybe my website could communicate with an android app ?

I don't know how to resolve my problem and I'm open to any idea.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FOSS jPOS library to utilize Zebra's barcode SDK:

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/scanning-systems/scanner-drivers-and-utilities.html

On that link scroll down to jPOS driver then continue to download. The jPOS library homepage is here:

http://jpos.org/

Beyond that there are some general purpose barcode scanning library which may work as well:

http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net

http://github.com/woo-j/OkapiBarcode

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will look at it. I'm also interested in the names of the barcode scanning library please.

Comment: @Knriano http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/    https://github.com/woo-j/OkapiBarcode

Comment: @Knriano Actually I believe Google also has a Java library for the ZXing reader you like as well, but maybe you already knew that. Just wanted to be sure. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.2.1